# How to handle dependent builds with massive "artifacts"

Tags: teamcity

We have a massive repository that builds a very large application and produces gigabytes of files. Our build time is between 1-2 hours depending on the 'age' :) of the build agent.

Most of the time we need the continuous integration of the build, e.g check if it compiles, etc.

Then sometimes we want to create an installer out of this massive repo with data from various locations of the working directory (it's not only the Bin/Release dir)

In Jenkins we did this by having two build jobs, one builds the code in his directory A and another job that creates the installer, but we forced its working directory to be set to A too.

Now we are testing TeamCity and I know things are different here.

I've been reading about snapshot and artifact dependency but I am not sure whether I get this right.

Let's say the checked out and build workspace after the build is virtually the entire artefacts pool as we need many things from a lot of locations in this workspace, e.g. binaries, assets, include header, config files, docs, etc.

One build with checked-out source and intermediate files is however about 30 Gb due to large set of external frameworks required to build and obj files. Without them the packaged thing would still be about 10 Gb and thousands of files.

If I set up the dependent build to run on the same machine with the same build it will still have to effectively store 10 Gb of artefacts on server, with caches on an agent, right? Even with cleanup the dependent build will need to receive the artefacts by copying them around?

I looked around and did not find that TeamCity does some smart junction or soft-copy of the data on the same agent just into another directory. Some of those assets are small and many, meaning that copying 10 gig is also quite slow.

Am I missing something about that concept? I know I can change the working dir of the installer config too but since those are created by some hash checksum of the projects settings I tend to mess with them.

For clarity: This is c++, a full rebuild and durations are acceptable (although not fun) for this size of the codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Currently agent sends artifacts to the server and artifacts are uploaded from the server when artifact dependent build starts. There is the related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-4339, please vote for it.
Current workarounds are (each with its own pros and cons):

- use caching proxy on a remote site so that once downloaded artifacts are cached and repeating downloads are quicker
- in your build script, copy artifacts in a shared directory on the build agent so that a user can download them later.  A build can then provide a simple HTML page with links to the files and the page can be made available as a build [report tab](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Including+Third-Party+Reports+in+the+Build+Results). However, only the artifacts built on the agent will be available from the agent with this approach
- mirror server artifacts to a remote site (e.g. overnight). Some third-party synchroniztion tool can be used to mirror .BuildServer/system/artifacts to the remote site
- use [Torrent plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Torrent+plugin) to speed up artifacts download